# Ordering class is not working under dropdown-menu Boostrap5.2

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

Using a list-group, the order class works fine but it is not working when I tried using it under the **[dropdown-menu](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/)**. Saw the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#order-classes) in bootstrap 5 about ordering of classes but can't make it to work inside the dropdown-menu.

See code sample below:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item order-5" href="#">Last</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item order-1" href="#">Should be first</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort order using `.order-*` class, the parent element should a flexbox. Here is how you can use that sort order

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu flex-column" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li class="order-5"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Last</a></li>
    <li class="order-1"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action A</a></li>
    <li class="order-1"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action B</a></li>
    <li class="order-0"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Should be first</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.dropdown-menu.flex-column.show {
    display: flex;
}
```

you need to write additional CSS because when dropdown-menu is showing the class `.dropdown-menu.show` is `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

The "order" class is part of Bootstrap's Flexbox utilities, the list-group class is creating a flexbox from your `<ul>` element, but dropdown-menu is not, and this is why ordering don`t work with dropdown-menu. But with a little modification you can order the dropdown-menu too.

```html
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <div class="row flex-column">
            <div class="order-5">
                <li class=><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Last</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="order-2">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="order-1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Should be first</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

With this modification the `<li>` elements are inside a flexbox, and "order" class can work now.